# How to cancel shutdown from the command line after issuing 'gnome-session-quit --power-off'

Tags: linux, rhel, gnome, shutdown

The operating system is Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2. When the battery gets to a certain chargining percentage in the system I work on, the following command is used to perform shutdown:

```
gnome-session-quit --power-off
```

It will display to the user a countdown of 60 seconds, which gives the user time to cancel the shutdown. In case the user didn't cancel yet, but plugged in the power cable, I would like to cancel the shutdown without the need for the user to press the 'cancel' button. Is there a way to cancel the shutdown from the command line?

I tried to kill the 'gnome-session-quit --power-off' process to see if it will cancel the shutdown, but it didn't.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

What about use `ps` command to find the power-off process and abort it with a `pkill` or `kill -9` or `killall`

====EDIT 03/26/21

An other possible solution of this issue is using `poweroff` command to `shutdown` so it can be cancelled by a `shutdown -c` which is a command which cancels a previously scheduled shutdown (even "now" is scheduled in this sense --- but whether the cancellation will prevent the reboot is a bit of a race in that case).

Comment: This does not work. Thank you for the try:)

Comment: Hi @rrrrTTTrrrr,

I was thinking about your issue, and I just wondering if maybe you are able to replace `poweroff` command to  `shutdown` so it can be cancelled by a 

`shutdown -c` 

which is a command which cancels a previously scheduled shutdown (even "now" is scheduled in this sense --- but whether the cancellation will prevent the reboot is a bit of a race in that case).

Comment: Hi, thank you for trying to help! This is what I did in the end, because I didn't find a way to cancel. So cheers!

Comment: Hey @rrrrTTTrrrr glad to hear you solved your issue, I've update my answer with the information shared, If you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, Thank you!